# Invalid "Use of unasigned local variable" when passing delegate to constructor which contains the constructing object?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to pass an `delegate` action to an object in its `constructor` parameter. In this `Action`, I would like to access a property which is defined in the object itself. Of course I want the property to be evaluated at execute-action-time.

Consider the following code:

```
public class BasicCommand
{
    private Action _action;
    public BasicCommand(Action action)
    {
         _action = action;
    }

    public int Parameter1 {get;set;}

    public void Execute()
    {
         _action.Invoke();
    }
}

public class SomeFooClass
{
    public void SomeFoo()
    {
        //use of unassigned variable here: obj
        BasicCommand obj = new BasicCommand(() => SomeOtherFoo(obj.Parameter1));

        obj.Execute();
    }

    public void SomeOtherFoo(int param)
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

This throws a compiler error: `Use of unasigned local variable`. But as I read it, the action will always be executed against an initialized object.

Am I mistaken?

Of course this can be easily fixed by setting the action by a public property. But I liked the idea to pass it directly into the constructor. Is this possible?

Comment: what is this - `public class BasicCommand(Action action)`?

Comment: what is that - `public SomeOtherFoo(int param)`?

Comment: possible typoes?this won't even compile.

Comment: The compiler error to me makes sense, you're trying to use obj.Parameter1 before obj has been created. I'm not sure that would ever work.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: it's just a code example. As well as the `SomeOtherFoo`. That it won't compile is obvious; the question is: is it possible to create such a (similar) pattern?

Comment: @Stefan You have major syntax errors that are completely unrelated to the question. It's perfectly reasonable that others point them out, and your question would be much improved by fixing them.

Comment: @DanielEdwards: I thought the `obj.Parameter1` would be evaluated at the time the delegate is executed. In that case it is a valid object. But as I said, I think i am mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that all in one statement. `obj` doesn't exist until that  statement has completed. It's referencing itself in it's own constructor essentially.

Comment: @hdv: ok, compiler errors fixed: my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hvd already explained, why it's not possible.
You could change it like so:

```
public class BasicCommand
{
    private Action<BasicCommand> _action;
    public BasicCommand(Action<BasicCommand> action)
    {
         _action = action;
    }

    public int Parameter1 {get;set;}

    public void Execute()
    {
         _action(this);
    }
}


public class SomeFooClass
{
    public void SomeFoo()
    {
        //use of unassigned variable here: obj
        BasicCommand obj = new BasicCommand((o) => SomeOtherFoo(o.Parameter1));

        obj.Execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, this was what I was looking for. I think I'll go find myself an other pattern though, or at least give it another thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Only your constructor should have a siginature similar to `ClassName(myArgs)`, not your class itself. So this should do it:

```
public class BasicCommand
{
    private Action _action;
    public BasicCommand(Action action)
    {
         _action = action;
    }

    public int Parameter1 {get;set;}

    public void Execute()
    {
         _action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

But there is still another error as you cannot use a member of an instance if it is not fully initialized. Thus `BasicCommand obj = new BasicCommand(() => SomeOtherFoo(obj.Parameter1));` won´t work.

EDIT: What you want to do would imply that you initialize the fields and properties (and delegates, events, ...) before actually accessing the constructor. What you may do however is store the property into a variable before creating the object and access that variable within your delegate:

```
var myProperty = // ...
BasicCommand obj = new BasicCommand(() => SomeOtherFoo(myProperty));
```

Comment: But are you sure about `obj` thing - that @Daniel pointed to?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I saw it already, pointed it out in my answer that this won´t work

Answer (score 1):

So what happens when you change your `BasicCommand` constructor to immediately invoke the action? It would then act on an uninitialised `obj`.

C# is designed to avoid fragile code. Its design makes it possible to determine whether `SomeFoo()` is valid C# without looking into the body of the `BasicCommand` constructor.

It's a design choice you might not agree with, and you might have legitimate reasons for picking a different design choice, but it's a valid one nonetheless.

Comment: This makes sense indeed, I overlooked the possibility the invoke in the constructor call.